# Woocommerce- Product addons | labels

Tags: woocommerce

I would like to ask a doubt :) I am just a beginner in WordPress and e-commerce. I am working on an e-commerce clothing website now and I would like to add product add-ons with labels on it. Like the screenshot. How is this possible? I have already purchased and installed product add-ons from woo commerce.
Any help would be much appreciated . Thanks!
[image: screenshot of desired outcome]

Comment: This looks more like [WooCommerce Variation Swatches](https://woocommerce.com/products/variation-swatches-and-photos/) than Product Add ons.

Comment: But When I looked at the code of this website its like Woocommerce product add-ons in the specific line

Comment: <div class="required-product-addon product-addon product-addon-1-select-your-size">

 
   <h3 class="addon-name">1. Select Your Size <abbr class="required" title="Required field">*</abbr></h3>
 
   <div class="addon-description"><p>Click on your tail size below</p>
</div> 
 <span class="radiowrapin">
 

 
  <input id="Big Sizes" type="radio" class="addon addon-radio" name="addon-93-1-select-your-size-0[]" data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="big-sizes"  />
        <label for="Big Sizes"> 
            Big Sizes        </label>

Comment: Could you help please